# What properties do hyperreal extensions of real functions have?

Tags: analysis, nonstandard-analysis

If I have a function $f : \mathbb R \to \mathbb R$ and extend it to the hyperreal function $f^* : \mathbb R^* \to \mathbb R^*$, what are some of the properties that I know $f^*$ must have?

Specifically, is there any "defining" property? That is, is there a property $P$ such that we can say

> $f^*$ is the only hyperreal function that agrees with $f$ on the reals and satisfies $P$

? (Analogously to how for any uniformly continuous function defined on a dense set, there is exactly one continuous extension defined on all reals)

**Edit**: Apparently, I didn't make it clear enough what, exactly, I am interested in, and I'm sorry for that. I am not asking which properties of $f$ carry over to $f^*$; I am asking, if you *don't know $f$*, which properties can still conclude $f^*$ must have.

To rephrase my question in a way that, I hope, eliminates this ambiguity: If you hav some function $g : \mathbb R^* \to \mathbb R^*$, what are some necessary conditions of the proposition

> There is some function $f : \mathbb R \to \mathbb R$ such that $g = f^*$

?

Comment: By the transfer principle, any first order statement about $f$ also holds for $f^*$. However, statements of the form "is the only function with" are possibly not first order. Nevertheless, for example the extension of the exponential is still its own derivative and should not be hard to still be the *only* such function

Comment: What framework for the hyperreals are you using?  Are you taking an ultraproduct, or an elementary extension, or something else?

Comment: @EricWofsey Uhmm, what? I am only aware of one way of constructing the hyperreals, which is defining a hyperreal to be some equivalence class of a sequence of reals, where the equivalence relation is given by an ultrafilter. What is this one called and how do the others differ?

Comment: @dankness: The short answer is you treat the hyperreals like you do the reals -- for nearly all practical purposes you just reason synthetically from basic properties without worrying what a number 'really is'. You only bother with things like Dedekind cuts or ultrapowers or whatever when you're specifically investigating foundations.

Answer (score 1):

The *comment* under your *question* pretty much says it all but it may be worth spelling it out in case you are not familiar with logical terminology. Consider the following two examples:

(1) definition of continuity of a function $f$ at $c$: $\forall\epsilon>0\;\exists\delta>0\;\forall x \;(|x-c|<\delta\implies|f(x)-f(c)|<\epsilon)$.

(2) completeness property of the real number field: $\forall S\subseteq\mathbb{R}$ if $S$ is bounded above then there exists a least upper bound for $S$.

I didn't bother writing out the fully formalized definition in (2) because the first quantifier is sufficient to illustrate my point.

The transfer principle applies to statements like (1) which involve quantification over elements only, but it does not apply directly to statements like (2) which involves quantification over *sets* of elements.

In fact, the completeness property (2) applied literally to the hyperreals would fail. Consider for example the set of all finite hyperreals.

In the comments the OP indicated that he is thinking in terms of the ultrapower construction of $\mathbb{R}^\ast$ relative to an ultrafilter $U$.  Then the condition that $g$ should be a natural extension is simply the following. Consider the restriction of $g$ to $\mathbb{R}$ and denote it by $f$.  Now apply the construction modulo the same ultrafiter $U$ to the function $f$, getting $f^\ast$. Now $g$ and $f^\ast$ must coincide at every hyperreal point.

A weaker condition is that $g$ must be given by an [*internal* set](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Internal_set) to begin with.

Comment: You seem to have understood the question pretty differently from how I intended it. I just clarified it in my edit. In particular, I don't see how (2) has anything to do with a function, and thus with my question.

Comment: The transfer principle applies just as well to (2) as to (1) -- in *both* cases you have to change the domain of quantification to its transfer: $\forall x \in X$ becomes $\forall x \in {}^\star X$.